# IP forwarding but getting ARP requests

Tags: networking, ip, ip-forward, arp

I have an issue with ip forwarding. Basically I have two interfaces:

> eth0 - 192.168.9.2 - Routes to internal network (192.168.20.0)

> eth1 - 192.168.8.100 - Routes to internet

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.9.2  netmask 255.255.255.252  broadcast 192.168.9.3
        inet6 fe80::4864:3a07:de69:4cfe  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:9c:07:bd  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14725  bytes 933855 (911.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 15977  bytes 8186253 (7.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eth1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.8.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.8.255
        inet6 fe80::e5b:8fff:fe27:9a64  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 121  bytes 16517 (16.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 829  bytes 69496 (67.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


pi@raspberrypi:~ $ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.8.1     0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 eth1
192.168.8.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     204    0        0 eth1
192.168.9.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.252 U     202    0        0 eth0
192.168.20.0    192.168.9.1     255.255.255.0   UG    20     0        0 eth0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

IP forwarding is enabled

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

When I try to ping out from eth1, I get no response. TCP dump also shows no packets.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo ping -I 192.168.9.2 4.2.2.2
PING 4.2.2.2 (4.2.2.2) from 192.168.9.2 : 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 340ms
```

Pinging from eth0 is fine.
If I ping from my local network on the interface facing eth0, I get no response.

```
admin@er4:~$ sudo ping -I eth1 4.2.2.2
PING 4.2.2.2 (4.2.2.2) from 192.168.9.1 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 4.2.2.2 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 6209ms
```

But it's trying to get the ARP entry for that destination.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo tcpdump host 4.2.2.2
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
19:16:14.894969 ARP, Request who-has b.resolvers.Level3.net tell 192.168.9.1, length 46
19:16:15.904174 ARP, Request who-has b.resolvers.Level3.net tell 192.168.9.1, length 46
19:16:16.944161 ARP, Request who-has b.resolvers.Level3.net tell 192.168.9.1, length 46
19:16:17.994377 ARP, Request who-has b.resolvers.Level3.net tell 192.168.9.1, length 46
19:16:19.024197 ARP, Request who-has b.resolvers.Level3.net tell 192.168.9.1, length 46
19:16:20.064207 ARP, Request who-has b.resolvers.Level3.net tell 192.168.9.1, length 46
19:16:21.104393 ARP, Request who-has b.resolvers.Level3.net tell 192.168.9.1, length 46
19:16:22.144260 ARP, Request who-has b.resolvers.Level3.net tell 192.168.9.1, length 46
19:16:23.184334 ARP, Request who-has b.resolvers.Level3.net tell 192.168.9.1, length 46
^C
9 packets captured
11 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I've done some googling and think i have to add an ip policy rule, but I can't seem to get it to work. I've tried

```
sudo ip rule add oif eth0 lookup default
```

but it makes no difference. I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What OS & release are you using?  You've listed a number of *deprecated* commands

Comment: It looks like the host "er4" has incorrect network mask for eth1 because it trying to reach address 4.2.2.2 as local address. Could you check if network mask is 255.255.255.252 and default gateway is 192.168.9.2 or show routing table on host "er4"?

Comment: `admin@er4:~$ show interfaces ethernet eth1
eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 74:83:c2:df:f9:47 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.9.1/30 brd 192.168.9.3 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::7683:c2ff:fedf:f947/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

Comment: Netmask looks ok. Could you show also routing table?